# Android navigation drawer: Dock item or group to bottom

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I would like to know how to dock a item or group to the bottom of the Navigation Drawer like in the Google Inbox app:

[image]

Couldn't find an option for that in my NavDrawer xml:

```
<item android:title="Generalt">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_send"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_lock_power_off"
            android:title="Log af" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Navigation Drawer `fragment`, you need to put a `scrollview` and inside it you have to put `LinearLayout` which will have your scrollable views and outside the scrollview you have to make another `LinearLayout` with `layout:gravity:bottom`, since it is outside the scrollview it won't scroll and remain at bottom :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your navegation drawer fragment, as #deep513 says. Here is an example, in this case I used a listview instead of scrollview, but this depends on your needs.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context=".NavigationDrawerFragment">


    <ListView
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
           android:dividerHeight="0dp"
           android:background="#cccc"
           android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Help"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Settings"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```